# how to Read data from CSV file and insert the data into Room Database?

Tags: android, database, csv, android-room

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.babynames);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    );
    String line = "";

    try {
        reader.readLine();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Line: " + line);

            String[] tokens = line.split(",");

            BabyName name = new BabyName();
            name.setGender(tokens[1]);
            name.setMeaning(tokens[2]);
            name.setName(tokens[3]);
            name.setOrigin(tokens[4]);


            babyNames.add(name);
            Log.d(TAG, "Just created: " + name);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.wtf("MyActivity", "Error reading data file on line" + line, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i am trying this but the app crashes and I got an error of array index out of bound and  in logs i am getting the data

Comment: Also post the error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BabyName name = new BabyName();
name.setGender(tokens[1]);
name.setMeaning(tokens[2]);
name.setName(tokens[3]);
name.setOrigin(tokens[4]);
```

shouldn't the index start from 0

```
name.setGender(tokens[0]);
```

Comment: the csv file contain some id i dont need them so i am starting it from token[1]

Comment: Can you look into my repo and tell me whats wrong i am doing  https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp

Comment: try to add break points and run in debug mode and see what line holds what value one by one, maybe your CSV file is corrupted. i don't see anything wrong in the code itself. plus from the look of your CSV file, i saw rows which contains quoted text such as "Sri shandarachary, founder of adwaitha philosophy", just split() wont work here.